# oracle subquery with order by not working

Tags: sql, oracle

when I run the following query:

```
select 
  (
    select  t.person_uid 
    from    table1 t 
    where   t.CELL_PH_NUM = table2.CELL_PH_NUM 
            and rownum<2
    order by t.created desc
  )
  from  temp table2 ;
```

...Oracle return the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I cannot understand where is the error:

1. If I remove the `order by`, the error is not returned and query is performed correctly (but doesn't return what I need)
2. If I run the subquery standalone (replacing `table2.CELL_PH_NUM` with a fixed value), the error is not returned and the query is returned correctly (but doesn't return what I need)

Where is the error?

Comment: Really not sure if this will give you what you want, have you tried structuring it like this?  `select ( select * from (select t.person_uid from table1 t where table1.CELL_PH_NUM = table2.CELL_PH_NUM order by table1.created desc) where rownum < 2 ) from temp table2 ;`

Comment: Have you tried adding an alias to the subquery?

Comment: thank you for your support. @NicholasSmith: I was shocked as well but I've done some tests with other tables and the seems that the rownum<2 is executed after the order_by. Furthermore i cannot follow your suggestion because table2.cell_ph_num is not visible from the sub-subquery

Comment: The condition `and rownum<2` only returns one row. It doesn't make sense to order one single row. An `order by` in a subquery can be ignored anyway, if there is not `fetch first n rows` applied, because according to the SQL standard data from a subquery is considered an unordered set. (Oracle violates the standard by relying on order when applying `rownum` on a subquery result, though.) I admit that the error message is inappropriate, but I guess what Oracle is trying to tell you is: there is an `order by` when there should be a closing parentheses instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't actually do what you want, because the `where` is applied before the `order by`.  So, you are not getting the most recent row, necessarily.

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't allow you to use another level of subqueries, because the correlation clause won't work.  But there is a solution:

```
select (select max(t.person_uid) keep (dense_rank first order by t.created desc)
        from table1 t
        where table1.CELL_PH_NUM = table2.CELL_PH_NUM 
       )
from temp table2 ;
```

In the version of the query in your question, `table1` is not defined.  That might be related to the error you are getting.

Comment: Regarding the depth of correlation Oracle will allow: Oracle documentation has always said (and still does as of 12.2) that it will allow only one level. Correlation at two or more levels of depth are not permitted. However, **in practice** both 10.1 and 11.1 allowed correlation at any depth (as required by the SQL Standard!), only for that to be "fixed" in 10.2 and 11.2. 12.1 again came with unlimited correlation depth, and that has NOT changed in 12.2 (even though the docs still say "no more than one level"). So, it depends strongly on one's version.

Comment: for the "table1" it was a typo (I've edited the question). Anyway I've done some experiment and I can assure you that the query is unexpectedly applying first the order num and then the rownum.

Comment: @DavideScicolone . . . The `order by` doesn't make a difference.  With or without it, the subquery will not return what you want (see the first sentence in this answer).  The filtering by `rownum` occurs *before* the sorting.